# SharePoint Workflow Codebeside Assembly and Class

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, codebeside

How can I find the codebeside assembly and class for a SharePoint workflow? For a workflow association (SPWorkflowAssociation) I want to find the name of the assembly and the name of the codebeside class for the workflow. After that I want to load the assembly and extract some information about the activities in the workflow. Please note, that I am not the one developing the workflow, it is a 3rd party workflow.

Comment: can you give a more detailed question? this makes no sence.

Comment: think he meant codebehind, not "codebeside".

Comment: in the context of WF, the term in codebeside, not codebehind

Answer (score 0):

Once the workflow is deployed (if packaged as a .WSP) it will reside in the GAC (C:\WINDOWS\assembly)

Note that there is no seperation between the codebeside class (yes, Aaron, that is the correct term within the context of WF) and the XOML that you use Visual Studio to design; it is all compiled into a single .dll (which as mentioned above is deployed via a WSP to the GAC)